# regex - match multiple field in string

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to find the Regex that will extract the fields 2, 3, 4 from this chain:

> **field('field2', field3, field4)**

- field is letters, always the same and not needed
- field2 is alphanumeric with some characters like: - _ @
- field3 and field4 are digits only (0000 or
  more)

here's some exemples of the chain :

> rooming('2003463071',100077,97297)
>
> rooming('Pierre_Garin',53030,4853)

I need to create an array with the 3 values.

I was doing it with :

> regExp = "('.+')"
>
> regExp = "([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{4})"
>
> or
>
> regExp ="(\w)"

but it's doesn't cover all the cases...
Is there a way to catch the 3 fields at once ?
One by one is also good.

As reference if someone can show me both way, it'll be a great help.

Cheers !

Comment: [Format your code properly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and remove the spelling errors in order to get help.

Comment: Couldn't you simply extract the part between parentheses and split on the commas?

Comment: try this: [^(]+\((([^,]+),)*([^,)]+)\) you can use the capturing groups to get the information out. A helpful website for constructing regular expressions is regexr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the single quotes and commas are always there, maybe this example helps...

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\('(.*?)',(\d+),(\d+)\)")

text = '''
rooming('2003463071',100077,97297)

rooming('Pierre_Garin',53030,4853)
'''

print(pattern.findall(text))
```

Outputs:

```
[('2003463071', '100077', '97297'), ('Pierre_Garin', '53030', '4853')]
```

Demo of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/auzkeI/1